# Need a LINQ statement - many to many relationship

Tags: vb.net, linq, dataset

I'm trying to write a program in vb.net that reads data from a webservice into a dataset.
I have that part working, giving me a dataset containing 3 tables.

`Student` contains StudentID, name, etc
`SubjectClasses` contains ClassID, name, department etc
`Collection` contains key, CollectionID, PersonID

`CollectionID` is the foreign key to `SubjectClasses` and `PersonID` is `StudentID`.

These are accessed by `myDataSet.tables("Student")`, `myData.tables("SubjectClasses")`, and `myData.tables("Collection")`

I need a query that will give me studentname, list of classes and departments

I've been looking at various LINQ statements on here and can't work out how to convert them to my needs.  So any help would be much appreciated.

the SQL if this were a MS Database would be...

```
SELECT Students.StudentID, Students.[prefered name], Classes.[class name]
FROM Students INNER JOIN 
(Classes INNER JOIN CollectionAssociates 
    ON Classes.ClassID = CollectionAssociates.CollectionID) 
    ON Students.StudentID = CollectionAssociates.PersonID;
```

Based on the 1st answer to this I now have the following, which returns NULL

```
Dim query = From row1 In myDataset.Tables("CollectionAssociates")
                Join row2 In myDataset.Tables("Student")
                On row1("PersonID") Equals row2("StudentID")
                Join row3 In myDataset.Tables("ClassDescription")
                On row1("CollectionID") Equals row3("ClassID")
                Select {row2("PersonID"), row2("PreferredFirstName"), row2("PreferredLastName"),
                     row2("YearGroup"), row2("TutorGroup"), row3("ClassDescription"), 
                     row3("SubjectDescription")}
```

Ok, after some more reading and tidying of code I now have....

```
Dim students = myDataset.Tables("Students")
Dim collection = myDataset.Tables("CollectionAssociates")
Dim classes = myDataset.Tables("ClassDescription")
Dim query = From student In students
            Join link In collection
            On student.Field(Of Integer)("StudentID") Equals link.Field(Of Integer)("PersonID")
            Join classDetail In classes
            On link.Field(Of Integer)("CollectionID") Equals classDetail.Field(Of Integer)("ClassID")
            Select New With {.name = student.Field(Of String)("PreferredLastName"), .class = classDetail.Field(Of String)("SubjectDescription")}
```

This produces a runtime error An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll

I can see the tables as datagridviews and the data is there and matches up with what I expect.
Hoping for help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u want as following

```
var Result = 
    from row1 in t1
    join row2 in t2 on row1.ID equals row2.ID
    join row3 in t3 on row1.ID equals row3.ID
    select new { ID = row1.ID, Col1 = row2.col1, Col2 = row3.col2 }
```

Comment: I think this is the sort of thing I need, but more specific, I cant convert this to vb.net or the specific tables I am using.

Comment: Ok, using this I have now solved my issue.  Thank you.  (I misnamed a table, Students should have been Student!!!)